# Make animation from output fortran files (txt files)

Tags: python, animation, matrix, text, gfortran

I wrote numerical code in Fortran which save result for each time step in text file as matrix format, for example matrix like this (100,000 , 500):

```
  0.000000000000000       0.100000000000000       0.200000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.120000000000000       0.203000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.130000000000000       0.205000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.140000000000000       0.206000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.100000000000000       0.207000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.050000000000000       0.208000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.070000000000000       0.209000000000000  
  0.000000000000000       0.060000000000000       0.210000000000000
```

and now I want to write code with Python which import these text data files as input files and by reading each row of these matrix, for output gives animation files (the format of files not important).

Does anyone know is this possible in Python because in Fortran its not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "animation"?  What should the graphs look like?

Comment: Hello , the animation file like GIF format or mpg format or  any format, I want to show change water level during the time (1D chart) as you can see the data in my comment , each row shows change water level in one time step .

Answer (score 0):

See the matplotlib package in python. There is a [nice tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) by Jake Vanderplas.